# What files to upload on the remote server from my asp.net mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to upload my asp.net mvc project to a server. I connected to the server via ftp and i don't know which files to upload prom the project. I have three folders, the names are .vs, Agenda(my project's name) and packages
and one file Agenda.sln.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio - Build, Publish has an FTP option that you can enter your FTP credentials and it will upload what needs to be uploaded.

If you want to do it a little more manually, publish to a folder on your hard drive and then copy those files manually (via FTP) to your web server. That will also show you which files need to be uploaded.

Mostly - you want the project file, but I would use the Publish option and look at the files it copies.